# What is the difference between a wordpress.com account and a wp-admin account?

Tags: wordpress

When I want to log into my blog as an admin, I need to go into mydomain.com/wp-admin and then log in with my user details.

Once logged in I can use the Wordpress.com functionalities and dashboard as any other Wordpress.com user would do.

However, when I want to sign into wordpress.com using the same details as for mydomain.com/wp-admin, I get a message saying that I do NOT have a wordpress account.

How is wordpress.com and the mydomain.com/wp-admin different? I thought that wp-admin stood for some sort of wordpress account log in?

Please excuse the basic question here, but I'm really confused.

Comment: `wordpress.org` is self-hosted. `wordpress.com` subcontracted hosting. `wordpress.com` can be compared to what shopify offers. it's a all-in one service. `wordpress.org` gives you more control overall, but usually require the user to have some knowledge. `wp-admin` is just the backend access to a self-hosted Wordpress website. In crude term, one service offer just the software, the other service offer software + hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress.com offers Wordpress sites as a service. You can host a blog or site there, even give it your own domain. However, the account you get is for Wordpress.com.

When you install Wordpress yourself, you set up a different account. You host the software yourself, and therefore have an admin account to use. That account is exclusive to that installation, which is great because it gives you more security. (The possibility to have one admin for multiple Wordpress sites is a modification of the single install, where you use the multisite version of Wordpress, but that is a completely different matter).

There's also wordpress.org. I'm not sure .com and .org accounts are shared, but a .org account might come in handy if you need support with plugins, you can collect your favorite plugins, etc.